# Gradle Code Editor Suggestions

Tags: gradle

Any suggestions for editing Gradle Scripts?
It would be nice to have some sort of IDE support with autocompletion (at-least at the Groovy level).

Currently the best thing that I can think of is just using Groovy Syntax Hightlighing with any standard editor such as TextPad, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the only IDE that actually has rudimentary DSL autocomplete support for Gradle is [SpringSource STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts). You will need to install the [Gradle plugin](http://static.springsource.org/sts/docs/latest/reference/html/gradle/).

Comment: As a side note: when using SpringSource STS with the gradle plugin, be sure to have the DSL Support enabled (Project/Gradle/Enable DSL Support).

Comment: As of STS v3.7.0, Gradle DSL Support has been discontinued.

Answer (score 6):

Intellij 11 supports gradle, see [their webhelp](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/gradle-2.html) for details.

An enhanced plugin appears to be scheduled for 11.1 in Q2 2012, [their wiki has a page](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/News) that acts as a worklog for the developer who is implementing it.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this link](http://www.gradle.org/tooling) for tooling advice from Gradle.

I use the [Groovy & Grails Tool Suite](http://grails.org/products/ggts) for Groovy support, it works great with the Gradle Eclipse plugin from the tooling site.

Comment: Both links are broken :-(

Answer (score 1):

When using eclipse you can use [EGradle](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egradle) IDE plugin which contains a good editor *(code completion ,syntax highlighting, outline +quick outline, parse error markup, ...)*. The  [EGradle Editor](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egradle-editor) is also available as  [standalone plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egradle-editor) without EGradle IDE.

If you are curious you can look at the [online documentation preview](https://rawgit.com/de-jcup/egradle/master/egradle-plugin-main/html/user_guide/editor.html) or the some of the [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnO8pgGpD7DlvsszAIjM26_2_0B9VJV4n) before.

**PS: I am the author of the mentioned plugin.**

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Android Studio**, it could be **Cucumber for Groovy** plugin.

[image]

Steps to install this plug in:

- on MacOS: **Preferences... -> Install JetBrains plugin... -> Cucumber
  for Groovy**.

[image]

Comment: FYI: Cucumber for Groovy/Java Plugin in Android Studio 4.0.1 prevents you from double-click and command/ctrl+click on symbols in source code which is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Found this for [Kotlin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html):

[image]

Cheers